# What would happen if a Pokemon used Me First on a target that was going to use Me First?

Tags: pokemon-series

If that happened, would the Pokemon who used Me First just keep using Me First or would it just say that the move failed?

Answer (score 8):

Me First will fail. The slower pokemon will then also fail.

Me First can only copy a damaging move. Despite the fact that it usually deals damage, Me First is a Status move so cannot be copied.

Source: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Me_First